# Silverlight Asp.net session keep-alive with heartbeat

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, authentication, timeout

What I need is persisting connection between SL app and Ria Services. After timeout passes, it throws exception on the first service call.

What I've tried to do is periodically call:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("../SomePage.aspx", UriKind.Relative));
```

and a service method:

```
svc.HeartBeat();
```

By periodically I mean once every X seconds, where X < timeout.

I was testing with 60s delay between heartbeats and authentication set to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Anyhow, after 3 minutes I get:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError        
Message: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Invoke operation 'HeartBeat' failed. Access to operation 'HeartBeat' was denied.
w System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
w System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation.Complete(Exception error)
w System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
w System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClass38.<InvokeOperation>b__34(Object )
```

and

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 09:46:37 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5108
Connection: Close

[Exception: Access denied.]
Pol.Backend.Web.SystemMessageViewer.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio\Abc.Web\SomePage.aspx.cs:13
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

(
Access denied is thrown when:

```
if (this.User == null || !this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    throw new Exception("Access denied.");
}
```

)

What else can I do?